# Make pool.apply_async wait to finish current jobs before submitting new jobs

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a nested for loop which I have used multiprocessing.Pool to parallize my inner loop. Here is an example code:

```
for i in range(N):
    for k in range(L):
        x[k] = Do_Something(x[k])
```

So as you can see, every iteration of `i` depends on the previous interation while the `k` for loop is "embarassingly" parallel with no dependance on which `k` finishes first. This naturally pointed me towards using appy_async.

The parallelize inner loop code looks something like this:

```
pool = mp.Pool(Nworkers)
for i in range(N):
    for k in range(L):
         pool.apply_async(Do_Something, args=(k), callback=getresults)
pool.join()
pool.close()
```

Writing the code this way screws up the order on the `i` loop since async does not wait for the `k` jobs to finish before moving on to the next `i` loop. The question is: **Is there a way to pause the async until all the jobs from the `k` loops finish before moving on to the next iteration of `i`?**. Using apply_async is benifical here since the callback allows me to store the results in a given order. I saw some other answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933561/wait-for-all-multiprocessing-jobs-to-finish-before-continuing), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387510/proper-way-to-use-multiprocessor-pool-in-a-nested-loop), but they uses alternative solutions like map, which seems like a valid alternative way, but I'd like to stick to apply_async here and wait for the jobs to finish...

I've also tried to stop and reinitalize workers on every iternation of `i`, but the overhead from mp.Pool() at every `i` is not very efficent... Heres what I tried:

```
for i in range(N):
    pool = mp.Pool(Nworkers)
    for k in range(L):
         pool.apply_async(Do_Something, args=(k), callback=getresults)
    pool.join()
    pool.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of issues with your current code:

1. The *args* parameter to the `apply_async` method takes an *iterable*, e.g. a `list` or `tuple`. You have specified `args=(k)` but `(k)` is not a tuple, it is just a parenthesized expression. You need `args=(k,)`.
2. Your calls to `pool.join()` and `pool.close()` are in the wrong order.
3. Your non-parallelized version specifies `x[k] = Do_Something(x[k])` where you are passing to the function argument `x[k]`. In your parallelized version you are just passing `k`. Which is correct? I will assume the former.

As you have already determined, `x[k]` starts out with some value and then when you invoke `x[k] = Do_Something(x[k])` `x[k]` ends up with a new value which will then be passed to `Do_Something` on the next iteration of variable `i`. Therefore, you do need to submit tasks and process results in a loop for each value of `i`. But you do not want to use a callback, which gets results in completion order instead of submission order. The call to `apply_async` returns a `multiprocessing.AsyncResult` instance. If you call method `get` on this instance it blocks until the submitted task ends and then fetches the result:

```py
pool = mp.Pool(Nworkers)

# Don't use a callback with apply_async, which
# gets results in completion order instead of
# submission order:
for i in range(N):
    # We must wait for all the return values are assigned
    # to x[k] before submitting tasks for the next i value:
    async_results = [
        pool.apply_async(Do_Something, args=(x[k],))
            for k in range(L)
    ]
    # Set the new values of x[k] for the next iteration
    # of the outer loop:
    for k in range(L):
        x[k] = async_results[k].get()
pool.join()
pool.close()
```

But simpler would be to use the `imap` method:

```py
pool = mp.Pool(Nworkers)

for i in range(N):
    # We must wait for all the return values are assigned
    # to x[k] before submitting tasks for the next i value:
    for k, result in enumerate(pool.imap(Do_Something, x)):
        x[k] = result
pool.join()
pool.close()
```

Or even the `map` method, which will create a new list and is less memory efficient (not an issue unless you are dealing with a very large `x`):

```py
pool = mp.Pool(Nworkers)

for i in range(N):
    # New x list:
    x = pool.map(Do_Something, x)
pool.join()
pool.close()
```

Here is a [minimal, reproducible
example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```py
# Successively square values. For N = 3, we are
# essentially raising a value to the 2 ** 3 = 8th power:

def Do_Something(value):
    """
    Square a value.
    """
    return value ** 2

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing as mp


    x = [2, 3]
    L = len(x)
    N = 3

    Nworkers = min(L, mp.cpu_count())

    pool = mp.Pool(Nworkers)

    for i in range(N):
        # New x list:
        x = pool.map(Do_Something, x)
    print(x)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```None
[256, 6561]
```

**But Better Yet Is ...**

If you can modify `Do_Something`, then move the looping on `i` to this function. In this way you are submitting fewer but more CPU-intensive tasks, which is what you would like:

```py
# Successively square values. For N = 3, we are
# essentially raising a value to the 2 ** 3 = 8th power:

N = 3

def Do_Something(value):
    """
    Square a value N times:
    """
    for _ in range(N):
        value = value ** 2
    return value

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing as mp


    x = [2, 3]
    L = len(x)

    Nworkers = min(L, mp.cpu_count())

    pool = mp.Pool(Nworkers)

    # New x list:
    x = pool.map(Do_Something, x)
    print(x)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

if you cannot modify `Do_Something`, then create a new function, `Do_Something_N`:

```py
# Successively square values. For N = 3, we are
# essentially raising a value to the 2 ** 3 = 8th power:

N = 3

def Do_Something(value):
    """
    Square a value.
    """
    return value ** 2

def Do_Something_N(value):
    for _ in range(N):
        value = Do_Something(value)
    return value

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing as mp


    x = [2, 3]
    L = len(x)

    Nworkers = min(len(x), mp.cpu_count())

    pool = mp.Pool(Nworkers)

    # New x list:
    x = pool.map(Do_Something_N, x)
    print(x)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```